# Using heroku_san gem, rake <app> logs:tail can't quit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, zeus, iterm2, heroku-san

Using iTerm2 on Mountain Lion, how can I stop the tail of logs on heroku?

Ctrl-C doesn't work.

Workaround is to kill the process id, but that is pretty inconvenient.

I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san/issues/159

I'm hoping there's some magic key combo for iTerm2.

I'm guessing that the issue is related to running the rake task within zeus. Here's the stack trace when ctrl-c is hit:

> ^Crake aborted!
>
> /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/api.rb:17:in
>   `system'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/api.rb:17:in`
>   block in sh'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/bundler-1.5.0.rc.1/lib/bundler.rb:229:in
>   `block in with_clean_env'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/bundler-1.5.0.rc.1/lib/bundler.rb:216:in`
>   with_original_env'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/bundler-1.5.0.rc.1/lib/bundler.rb:222:in
>   `with_clean_env'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/api.rb:17:in`
>   sh'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/stage.rb:126:in `logs'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/tasks.rb:267:in`block (4 levels) in '
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/project.rb:61:in
>   `block in each_app'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/project.rb:60:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/project.rb:60:in
>   `each_app'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/tasks.rb:321:in`each_heroku_app'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/heroku_san-4.3.2/lib/heroku_san/tasks.rb:266:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus/rails.rb:111:in`
>   rake'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:116:in
>   `block in command'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:103:in`
>   fork'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:103:in
>   `command'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:80:in`
>   block (3 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:80:in
>   `fork'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:80:in`
>   block (2 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in`
>   block in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in
>   `loop'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in`
>   go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in
>   `block (3 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in`
>   fork'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in
>   `block (2 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in
>   `block in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in`
>   loop'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in
>   `go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in`
>   block (3 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in
>   `fork'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in`
>   block (2 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in`
>   block in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in
>   `loop'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in`
>   go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in
>   `block (3 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in`
>   fork'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:78:in
>   `block (2 levels) in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:73:in
>   `block in go'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in`
>   loop'
>   /Users/justin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/zeus-0.13.3/lib/zeus.rb:62:in
>   `go'
>   -e:1:in`' Tasks: TOP => logs:tail => heroku:logs:tail (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Please consider using either GitHub or StackOverflow. OpenSource maintainers will be thankful for not spamming them.

Comment: I just installed version 4.3.2 of heroku_san using it against the cedar stack and it is no problem to exit the logs:tail task.